# using background image in :after Pseudo class

Tags: css

I need to show a icon after the H3 tag, Below is the code I am using. But its not working;

```
h3:after{
content: "";
background: url(down-arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
width:24px;
height:24px;
color:#666666;}.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need `display: block` or `display: inline-block` as well.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wH7gp/